# segmentation fault when building postgres GiST index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, segmentation-fault, postgresql-9.4

I'm using postgres 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I execute this query:

```
create index a_idx on my_table using gist(my_column);
```

I'm getting error:

```
erver closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!>
```

In the logs I can see this:

```
2016-04-21 11:30:11 BST LOG:  server process (PID 7850) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

I checked if this column has any null values but it doesn't.
How can I debug this?

The structure of `my_table` is:

```
                    Table "public.my_table"
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | integer | not null  | plain    |              |  
 my_column | bfp     |           | extended |              |
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure? What type is `my_column`?

Comment: @IldarMusin - I edited my question to provide the information you were asking for.

Comment: And the type `bfp` is a User Defined Type?

Comment: Yes, a binary fingerprint: https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/fa79611dd7654d5cf02cb32d7c38d2cb29ce5361/Code/PgSQL/rdkit/adapter.cpp#L656

Comment: Then it seems that problem is in `bfp`. You probably should report this bug to the developers, it crashes postgres.